# Low Power Switching application With N-Mosfet

Tags: low-power, switching, nmos

In my application I need to effectively switch on or off a very small load, around 0.5W to 1W. Also, I need to ensure that power loss is kept to a minimum. The voltage levels of my application will not exceed 5-10V. Correct me if I am wrong, but I think that the main consideration when looking to optimize the mosfet's power losses would be for it to have the minimum Rds(on) possible (of course considering that it meets the application's other specifications). Let me also add that The switching on will be occurring for a small amount of time every other hour or so, so I thing that the turn on-off characteristics of the mosfet would not play a significant role here.

Based on that, after looking at the available options, I found out that the mosfets that have the lowest Rds (on) are designed for very high power applications and can withstand very large voltages ([STP55NF06L for example)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stp55nf06l.pdf), which is completely unnecessary for my application.

On the other hand, smaller mosfets (like [BSS214N for example](https://www.acdcshop.gr/content/BSS214NH6327XTSA1.pdf)) that can withstand much lower power, have a significantly larger Rds (on).

Overall, am I missing something in the above-mentioned thoughts? What else should I consider for my application

Comment: The parametric tables at Vishay http://www.vishay.com/mosfets/ show a number of devices in a SOT-23 footprint with less than 20 milliohm Rds(on) for 20V Vds parts. Certainly ultra low on resistance is usually found in power devices, but with the advances over the years there are many parts designed for low power (and low losses for applications such as IoT) with low on resistances. This is but one manufacturer. Diodes.com is another supplier.

Comment: Do you have other (price/size) constraints? Is this a hobby project, or some large-scale manufactured device? For hobby, choosing a "popular" part that will be available later can be an advantage, also you could put in a massively overkill part and stop worrying. For a 100k batch every cent matters.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need a **number** for what is an acceptable loss rather than "..kept to a minimum", which will usually lead you down the wrong path.

For example, if the voltage is 5V and the power is 10W the current will be 2A. A maximum acceptable loss might be 2% or 100mV, meaning 200mW loss in the MOSFET when 'on'.

That implies an Rds(on) of 50m\$\Omega\$ or less. You can search for MOSFETs with such a characteristic. My go-to SOT-23 N-channel MOSFET for switching significant current is the [AO3400](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/ao3400.pdf) which has a guaranteed Rds(on) of 33m\$\Omega\$ at 4.5V Vgs (it will be higher for higher Tj, but still less than 50m\$\Omega\$ under reasonable conditions). It's a very cheap small part.

You can find other parts in SOT-23 with even lower Rds(on) or go to other packages (NXP - now Nexperia has some nice parts) that have a bigger die and are better (for a price). For example (at the low end of Rds(on), the [PSMN0R9-25YLC](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/PSMN0R9-25YLC.pdf)
 which has 1.25m\$\Omega\$ maximum Rds(on) at room temperature.

It's **not** a good idea to go completely overboard on the Rds(on) parameter- the larger MOSFETs tend to have much higher capacitance, so they switch slower, and of course they tend to cost considerably more. That particular one is USD 0.54 in 1,500 quantity vs. USD 0.085 in 3K (one reel in each case), so more than 6x the cost. Actual cost differential in large production quantity is likely a larger percentage. Somewhere in between might be a better choice.

tl;dr  Determine a specification for performance and other characteristics and do a **parametric search**. Iterate if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider the entire Power Distribution Network from source to load.

When you consider battery ESR, contact resistance, wire resistance and PCB trace resistance, you will likely find any logic level FET with an RDSon of less than 100 mOhms is just fine.

Depending on the load duty-cycle, the drain leakage current for Vgs = 0V, may be another significant element in your power budget (but highly unlikely).

P.S. A 1 oz copper trace has a resistance of approximate 0.5 mOhm/sq.